# Rails - cannot precompile assets in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-ec2, assets

I deployed a Rails app to Amazon EC2, but while deploying I got

```
find: `/path/to/root/releases/20130514204835/public/stylesheets' (the same for javascripts and images)
```

Then I've tried to precompile asset on my machine - **rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production** or **bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production** - but in both cases I got the same error:

```
/Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bin/ruby /Users/radek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
rake aborted!
Access denied for user 'adam'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

The access to MySQL should be ok, what is wrong with the assets?

Comment: Does your web server have access to the files?

Comment: How can I find out it?

Comment: If your MySQL works the MySQL user has access to your rails app. Find out which user your web server runs as, if it's apache sometimes it's apache2 or httpd, then type groups <web server-user> to see what groups your webserver belongs to. See which groups MySQL has access to, an if its missing add the webserver user to that group so it has access to the rails app so it can serve up those assets.